# how to save a mp3 file in jsp?

Tags: jsp

I have a mp3 file which I am sending through namevalue pairs and I have to get that mp3 file decode it in server side and save it in a folder in server side using jsp.How can I do that.?can anyone give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you want to be able to upload a file to your JSP. First of all, a JSP is used to generate markup, so you should upload the file to a servlet or action, but not to a JSP.

All the MVC frameworks (Stripes, Spring MVC, etc.) have native support for file uploads. They would also help structure your application. If you really don't want to use such an MVC framework, then use [Apache commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).